# pagination is not working ?single entry across multiple pages

Tags: channel-entries, pagination

```
{exp:channel:entries category_group="16" limit="1" paginate_type="field" paginate="bottom"}

    <div class="anw-readmorenewstitle">{title}</div>

    <div class="anw-readmorenewstext">{news_text}

    <div class="article-content-columns">
    {multi_field="Summary|Extended"}
    </div>

    <div>
        Last updated on {edit_date format='%M %d, %Y'} at {edit_date format='%h:%i %A'}<br />
    </div>

    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages for this article {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is the code i am using.The result of the above code  is not showing any pagination links.  when i remove the  `{multi_field}` tag  pagination links are appearing,but  link route to next news. I want to  split a long article in to different pages..

plz help